# delphi Xe5 + Android: erro ao instalar APP no Sony Xperia e1

Tags: android, delphi

A aplicação roda bem no Samsung e no LG, mas no Xperia E1 não mostra o ícone nem abre o banco de dados (avisa que o interbase não está instalado).

O que pode estar faltando? O que falta fazer?

Answer (score -1):

O problema já foi resolvido. Nem é falha da versão nem questão de compatibilidade, apenas algum detalhe de como o Android do xperia trata maiúsculas/minúscula nos nomes de arquivos.

Recriei o banco e mudei todas as referências a campo e arquivo, tanto no programa como no banco, para maiúsculas, e reinstalei as licenças usando os default do "deployment" (antes estavam em diretório à parte) e funcionou bem.

Answer (score -2):

Primeiro verifique se o aparelho é compatível com a sua versão de delphi.
segue uma lista 
http://williamduarte.com.br/lista-android-compativel-delphi/.
Lembrando que a lista não deve estar atualizada.
No meu caso uso, Delphi xe7 e rodou no meu LG L70, que não está na lista.
Provavelmente possa ser algum outro problema, tente executar um app simples e veja se roda.

Comment: o aparelho é compatível sim, pois nele já consegui rodar app que usa a câmara e acessa um banco sqlite. Rodou blz... 

Penso que o problema  talvez seja de autorização ou proteção ao acesso aos arquivos da licença e do ícone.

Answer (score -3):

Acredito que essas "Falhas" são devido a versão do seu Delphi, tente roda-las em um Delphi XE7 update 1  ou mais recente, acredito que já tenha corrigido essa falha.